# Can you dynamically create variable names in Mathematica?

Tags: variable-definitions, files-and-directories, variable

I was wondering if there is a way of Mathematica to read a string or number and create variable with that name.

For instance imagine that I have a file with the word data1. I would want to create a variable called "data1".

On the other hand, imagine that I read a number from that file "N". And then I want to do a for cycle to create N variables called data%d where %d goes from 1 to N. Is there a way to do this in Mathematica?

Thank you!

EDIT:

So using the suggestion I was given in fact doing this piece of code works:

```
data1=ToExpression[data1]
data1 = 3
data1
```

It prints out 3.

However when I do:

```
Data = {{"Field1", "Field2", "Field3"}, {"LP", 30, 2}}
For[i = 1, i <= Length[Data[[1]]], i++, Data[[1]][[i]] = ToExpression[Data[[1]][[i]]]];
For[i = 1, i <= Length[Data[[1]]], i++, Data[[1]][[i]] = Data[[2]][[i]]];
Field1
```

Field1 prints out Filed1 instead of printing out LP. Any guess of what I am doing wrong? I want to be able to manipulate variable Field1 with value LP. Thank you.

Comment: **I would want to create a variable** you mean you want to convert string to a Symbol of that name? Then use `ToExpression["data1"]` And for the rest you can do `Table[ToExpression["data" <> ToString[n]], {n, 1, 10}]` ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjoEW.png) I think your question has been asked before but hard to find now.

Comment: Yes that was what I've meant, thank you!

Comment: There is also the function "Symbol"

Comment: Also have a look at `Unique`.

Comment: Hi @Nasser can you please take a look at my edit? Thank you!

Comment: Please consider using `Association`, it is rarely justified to create symbols on a fly. It is costly and cumbersome.